# Javascript Rewrite Config File

Tags: javascript

I have a config.js file which I believe is JSON which is called when the application first starts:

```
var config={};
config.user = [
    {id:'JSMITH', priceModify:'true'},
    {id:'JBLOGGS', priceModify:'false'},
]
config.price = [
    {id:"price01", name:"priceName01", primary:"57.25", secondary:"34.54"},
    {id:"price02", name:"priceName02", primary:"98.26", secondary:"139.45"},
    {id:"price03", name:"priceName03", primary:"13.87", secondary:"29.13"}
]
```

To pull / push data I just use the following:

```
// Read
var curPrice = config.price[0].primary;

// Write
config.price[0].primary = "98.24";
```

How do I go about exporting the config file with the new value so that it will load next time the application is opened? I can use the file system object to write the file, I just don't understand how I would export everything (and preferably keep the same format).

I originally thought about reading the whole config file into a variable, cycling through to find the required block, id, and key and replacing the value, then writing the whole thing back, but I can't seem to figure out how to replace that specific value only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit** Apologies, I forgot to mention that this application is completely offline and uses local directories

**Solution**
I stumbled across a few solutions to different issues which, when combined, gave me the perfect solution. First we cycle the Javascript object, building an array of the detail and then converting the array to a string:

```
vMethod.convertToText = function(obj) {
    var string = [];
    var output = '';
    var count= 0;
    var countTotal = 0;
    if (typeof(obj) == "object" && (obj.join == undefined)) {
        count= 0;
        countTotal = 0;
        string.push("{");
        for (prop in obj) {
            countTotal++;
        }
        for (prop in obj) {
            if(count==countTotal - 1) {
                string.push(prop, ": ", vMethod.convertToText(obj[prop]),'}\r\n');
            } else {
                string.push(prop, ": ", vMethod.convertToText(obj[prop]), ",");
            }
            count++;
        };
    } else if (typeof(obj) == "object" && !(obj.join == undefined)) {
        count= 0;
        countTotal = 0;
        string.push("[\r\n")
        for (prop in obj) {
            countTotal++;
        }
        for(prop in obj) {
            if(count==countTotal - 1) {
                string.push(vMethod.convertToText(obj[prop]),'];\r\n');
            } else {
                string.push(vMethod.convertToText(obj[prop]), ",");
            }
            count++;
        }
    } else if (typeof(obj) == "function") {
        string.push(obj.toString())
    } else {
        string.push(JSON.stringify(obj))
    }

    output = string.join("").toString();
    //output = output.slice(1, -1);     
    return output;
}
```

Then we clean the array (neccessary for me to remove excess characters)

```
vMethod.cleanConfigText = function() {
    var outputText = vMethod.convertToText(config);
    outputText = outputText.slice(1, -1);
    outputText = 'var config = {};\r\n'+outputText;
    outputText = outputText.replace('user:','config.user =');
    outputText = outputText.replace(',price:','config.price =');
    outputText = outputText.slice(0, -2);
    outputText = outputText.replace(/"/g, "'")
    return outputText;
}
```

Finally a function to export the object into my config.js file:

```
vMethod.writeToConfig = function() {
    vObject.fileSystem = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    vObject.fileSystemFile = vObject.fileSystem.CreateTextFile('source\\js\\config.js',true);
    vObject.fileSystemFile.Write(vMethod.cleanConfigText());
    vObject.fileSystemFile.Close();
    delete vObject.fileSystemFile;
    delete vObject.fileSystem;
}
```

So when I want to export a change in the config, I just call:

```
    vMethod.writeToConfig();
```

The only difference in the file format is that the commas appear at the start of a trailing line rather than the end of a preceding line but I can live with that!

**Edit** Turns out I'm anally retentive and the commas were bugging me

Added these to the clean up function and now the config is identical to before but without the indent

```
    outputText = outputText.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '_');
    outputText = outputText.replace(/__,/g, ',\r\n');
    outputText = outputText.replace(/__/g, '\r\n');
```

Thank you to those that looked at the question and tried to help, very much appreciated.

**Edit**
DO NOT READ THE SOLUTION ABOVE, IT IS IN THE WRONG PLACE AND THERFORE IS NOT A VALID ANSWER. YOU'VE BEEN WARNED.

Comment: Is this client side? Then you can't write to file. Use localStorage instead: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Completely offline, it is a HTA based on a file server.

Comment: If the first code block is exactly the contents of config.js, it's not JSON, it's a plain ol' javascript object

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how your having issues replacing that specific value, can you tell us what do you expect and what happens?

Comment: JaromandaX Ah, thanks for clearing that up. @Olvai I want the new primary price of (for example) 98.24 to be written the config file, so that when the application is rebooted (or crashes), the price will not be lost. so the new config file would show '{id:"price01", name:"priceName01", primary:"98.24", secondary:"34.54"}',

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very popular npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile . There are many but I've choosen this one.

Usually config stuff should be in json or .env files.

Now, all you have to do is use `jsonfile`'s API to read/write JSON and parse (the package does the serialization/deserialization) it at the beginning when the application starts.

Example:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var util = require('util');
var config = null;
var file = './config.json';

// Reading
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
  config = obj;
});

// Writing

// Edit your config blah blah
config.user = [
    {id:'JSMITH', priceModify:'true'},
    {id:'JBLOGGS', priceModify:'false'},
];

config.price = [
    {id:"price01", name:"priceName01", primary:"57.25", secondary:"34.54"},
    {id:"price02", name:"priceName02", primary:"98.26", secondary:"139.45"},
    {id:"price03", name:"priceName03", primary:"13.87", secondary:"29.13"}
];

jsonfile.writeFile(file, config, function (err) {
  if(err) return err;

  console.log('Config saved to file!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kappaismyname, but isn't 'require' specific to node?

Comment: Haven't you said it's a node app ? This is for node, if you want in browser you can use localStorage or by storing the config persistently in a database.

Comment: Nope, it's a HTA, completely offline and runs on a file server

Comment: Oh, okey. Isn't HTA like, '99 ways of doing stuff ?

Comment: It certainly is, everything will soon be rewritten with pure Java to accommodate deprecation, but until that happens I'm stuck using HTAs unfortunately

Comment: Thanks anyway for taking the time to look at it